# CTMMobile - Vtiger

Tags: php, mobile, vtiger, vtigercrm

i have an error in the communicate by SMS block.

It does not take the value of the mobile number, it literally takes the variable $ mobile

```
Send SMS

    Array
    (
    [to] => $ mobile
    [from] => Adoc365
    [content] => Welcome Adoc365
    )

Exception occured: E_ERROR
```

Does anybody know where this error is comming from?

```
E_ERROR # ClockWorkSMS Error: To: $mobile Error 10: Invalid 'To' Parameter
```

Kind regards

Comment: How do you set this value? (BTW the space may be important as it is `$ mobile` and not `$mobile`)

Comment: Probelm was solved. You were right Nigel, it was that case with the $ mobile thing.